# Print only the letters after matching in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I want to print 12:40:56 from 2021-01-19T12:40:56.671773769Z in bash. I tried using sed and awk. But it is not working. This is what I tried with sed.

```
get_time= docker inspect "containerid" | grep `cut -d -f1 4`
#which give output as 2021-01-19T12:40:56.671773769Z
start= $get_time | grep `sed -n -e 's/^.*T: //.'`
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also, the way you assign your variables does not make sense. If you really would write it like this, `get_time` and `start` would be empty, and you would also get an error message. Please at least make the code free of syntax errors before posting it here.

Comment: Copy/paste it into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about then post a question here if you still have one.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it hasn't been run through shellcheck.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, simplest solution could be make delimiters as `T` OR `.` and print the 2nd field, completely based on your shown samples only.

```
echo "$get_time" | awk -F'[T.]' '{print $2}'
```

***2nd solution:*** Using `match` function try following, using a regex to match values of time here.

```
echo "$get_time" | 
awk 'match($0,/T([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}'
```

***3rd solution:*** Using `gsub` function to perform global substitution as per needed condition here.

```
echo "$get_time" | awk '{gsub(/.*T|\..*/,"")} 1'
```

***NOTE:*** All 3 solutions are written and tested with shown samples only in GNU `awk`.

Comment: There's no such thing called as a input file. What should I replace it with that?

Comment: @Siddharth, no issues, pass it as a variable value to `awk` then :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `2021-01-19T12:40:56.671773769Z` is the value of the `get_time` variable, you can use `sed`:

```sh
start=$(sed -n 's/.*T\(.*\)\..*/\1/p' <<< "$get_time")
```

Here,

- `-n` - suppresses the default line output
- `.*T\(.*\)\..*` matches any text, then `T`, then captures any text up to the last `.` into Group 1 (`\1`), and then `\.` matches a dot and `.*` matches the rest of the string, and
- `\1` - replaces the whole matched string with the  Group 1 value
- `p` - prints the result of the substitution.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/GuIMqp):

```sh
s='2021-01-19T12:40:56.671773769Z'
sed -n 's/.*T\(.*\)\..*/\1/p' <<< "$s"
```

Answer (score 1):

A pure bash solution using `extglob`:

```sh
s='2021-01-19T12:40:56.671773769Z'
shopt -s extglob
echo "${s//@(*T|.*)}"

12:40:56
```

Or without `extglob`:

```sh
s='2021-01-19T12:40:56.671773769Z'
p="${s#*T}"
echo "${p%%.*}"

12:40:56
```

or a single line `grep`:

```sh
grep -Eo '([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}' <<< "$s"

12:40:56
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En 's/.*(..:..:..).*/\1/p' file
```

Pattern match on the date and remove everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `AWK` following way:

```
echo '2021-01-19T12:40:56.671773769Z' | awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]"}{print $1}'
```

output

```
12:40:56
```

Explanation: `awk` when given `FPAT` looks for matches in line and assign subsequent matches in line to column, as there is single match it ends in 1st column, which is then `print`ed.

I want to note that your timestamp looks like it have fixed width for year month day, if it is case simpler solution might be to just take substring.